# Why didn't Lynyrd Skynyrd ever record "Powderfinger"?

Tags: cover

According to Wikipedia, the Neil Young song "Powderfinger" was to appear on Lynyrd Skynyrd's next album.

Because of Ronnie van Zandt's death, this didn't happen.

Does anyone know why the song was never used by Lynyrd Skynyrd?

Comment: The band didn't play from 1977-1987, the 10 years after air crash. Probably that's why

Comment: And by 1987 it was really Neil Young's song because he'd released his version in 1979. Makes sense, thanks!